# Possibility of same certificate imported to java key store

Tags: duplicates, keystore, ca, jks

If I am importing CA certificates to java key store, is it possible to import the duplicate certificate to java key store?

What happens if am importing a certificate which is already existing in JKS. Is it possible?

Comment: No, actually there is an existing key store with the certain set of certificates. Then am importing a new set of certificates to existing one, so like to check is there any way to know that certificate already exists.

Comment: So create a new key store for testing, and try to import the same cert twice.